# Recyclerview onClickListener not working in Android with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. How to set it?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set an onClickListener on my recyclerview. I retrieve data from Firebase and am able to load the data in the recyclerview. When I set an onClickListener nothing happens. How can I solve this?

```
class PersonAdapter(
    options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Person>,
) : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Person, PersonAdapter.personsViewholder>(options) {


inner class personsViewholder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)
        var description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription)
        var image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto)
}



 override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: personsViewholder,
        position: Int, model: Person
    ) {


        holder.title.text = model.title

        holder.description.text = model.description
}
```

I tried:

```
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { doSomething() }
```

and

```
init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val position: Int
                Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "You clicked on this item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

I use an Fragment Class instead of an Activity if that makes a difference.

onCreateViewHolder:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): personsViewholder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_person, parent, false)
        return personsViewholder(view)
    }
```

item layout:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fitone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subintropage">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What does "doSomething()" do?

Comment: Just a test to see if it runs a line of code when I am clicking, like a println or Log